# Universal Windows 8.1 Build simple tree structure

Tags: c#, dom, windows-runtime, treeview, windows-8.1-universal

I am reletevely new to Windows Apps development. Not sure if I am right or wrong, but I believe that there is no tree structure in Windows 8.1 apps. If I am wrong or anyone has a solution how I could include a simple tree structure in my app would be really appreciated.

Note: I'm working with C#, Visual Studio 2015, WinRT (Windows Universal 8.1 / Windows Phone 8.1 [phone is not necessery at this point]).

Thanks for answers in advance!

Comment: When you say "tree structure" are you referring to some kind of tree UI element? Also are you targeting UWP *or* WinRT? They're two different APIs.

Comment: Sorry for missunderstanding. I'm targeting WinRT (its Universal Windows 8.1 type project). What I want in the end is my data (form ObservableCollection or any other) displaid as a tree. Kind of what you would see with F12 Tools, DOM explorer tree.

Answer (score 1):

WinRT doesn't have any built-in XAML control for displaying tree data, if I remember correctly (at least not anything like the DOM explorer tree in F12 tools). But you can always roll your own control, or adapt the [TreeView](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit/blob/master/WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/TreeView/TreeView.cs)
control from the WinRT XAML toolkit.

Comment: Would you be able to give some examples (samples) of WinRT XAML Toolkit TreeView or is it too complicated?

Comment: You should get a nuget package from https://www.nuget.org/packages/winrtxamltoolkit/ and then check the samples project on https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit. The actual sample XAML is here: https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit/blob/master/WinRTXamlToolkit.Sample/Views/Controls/TreeViewTestView.xaml

Comment: Oh, I only noticed you're targeting Windows 8.1 rather than 10. In that case you might need to get an older version of the NuGet package for your project from https://www.nuget.org/packages/winrtxamltoolkit/1.6.1.3